# perl XML::Simple attributes blank

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, xml-simple

I'm trying to parse some XML into Perl, but testing isn't yielding what I'd expect.

```
$buffer = qq[<DeliveryReport><message id="msgID" sentdate="xxxxx" donedate="xxxxx" status="xxxxxx" gsmerror="0" /></DeliveryReport>];

$xml = XML::Simple->new( ForceArray => 1 );

$file = $xml->XMLin($buffer) or die "Failed for $reply: $!\n";
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($file);

$msgid          = $file->{message}->{id};
$message_status = $file->{message}->{status};
print "OUTPUT: $msgid  $message_status";
```

but the output is blank and the `print Dumper` looks wrong regards id attribute but I'm not sure why.

```
$VAR1 = {
    'message' => {
        'msgID' => {
            'status' => 'xxxxxx',
            'gsmerror' => '0',
            'sentdate' => 'xxxxx',
            'donedate' => 'xxxxx'
        }
    }
};
```

OUTPUT:

Here is the final code working correctly.

```
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

$xml = XML::Simple->new (KeyAttr=>'',ForceArray => 1);
$file = $xml->XMLin('

<DeliveryReport>
    <message id="msgID1" sentdate="xxxxx" donedate="xxxxx" status="xxxxxx" gsmerror="0" />
    <message id="msgID2" sentdate="yyy" donedate="yyy" status="yyy" gsmerror="0" />
</DeliveryReport>
                ') or die "Failed for $reply: $!\n";

print Dumper($file);


$numOfMsgs = @{$file->{message}};
print "<br /><br />I've received $numOfMsgs records<br />";

for($i = 0; $i < $numOfMsgs; $i++) {

     $msgid = $file->{message}->[$i]->{id};
     $message_status = $file->{message}->[$i]->{status};

     print "message id: [$msgid]<br />";
     print "status id: [$message_status]<br />";
     print "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, XML::Simple chooses to fold around the following keys by default: `name`, `key`, `id` (see [note 1](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm#KeyAttr_=%3E_%5B_list_%5D_#_in+out_-_important)).

Your XML schema contains the `id` key, which is why the hash is being split there. You can clear the `KeyAttr` value when you create your object (e.g. `$xml = XML::Simple( KeyAttr=>"" );`) to override the default behavior.

Your output, with multiple `message` entries, would look like:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'message' => [
                       {
                         'gsmerror' => '0',
                         'status' => 'xxxxxx',
                         'id' => 'msgID',
                         'donedate' => 'xxxxx',
                         'sentdate' => 'xxxxx'
                       },
                       {
                         'gsmerror' => '1',
                         'status' => 'yyyyyy',
                         'id' => 'msgID2',
                         'donedate' => 'yyyyy',
                         'sentdate' => 'yyyyy'
                       }
                     ]
        };
```

So you need to adjust your code slightly to account for `%message` containing an array of message hashes. The format would be the same for a single `message` if you keep the `ForceArray` option, so your code change would work for both cases.

Comment: They say the format is as follow:

<DeliveryReport>
<message id="msgID" sentdate="xxxxx" donedate="xxxxx" status="xxxxxx" gsmerror="0"/>
.....
</DeliveryReport>

I won't know the msgID to select them.

Comment: I updated the answer to better address the issue of folding around `id`.

Comment: That does seem to fix the problem but if there only one message it no long works as there no array. Adding ForceArray => 1 back fixed that. So I just need a way to know how many records I have then I can loop them. Off to check the docs.

Comment: You can find the array size by evaluating the array reference in scalar context, like `my $size = @{$file->{message}};`

Comment: Thanks Ben, it occurred after I posted. I'll update my question with the changes.